# Can we use Bitbucket Data center to create build pipelines in Azure Devops / VSTS?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, bitbucket, devops

I have used Github and Azure Git repo to build Azure DevOps build and release pipelines. 
Now I have to use Bitbucket Data center to do the same. Is it possible to use Bitbucket data center?
If yes, how do I go about and what option to choose in the Select repo (Visual designer) form to create it?
[Select repo in Azure devops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu2ZY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally. So the answer is to use the External git option from the options available as Bitbucket DC is finally a Git repo. We will have to use the ssh keys / url to configure this option.

Comment: this is exactly what I mentioned in my last comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitbucket repos in Azure build\release pipelines, but only with visual ui, yaml is not yet supported for bitbucket. And in terms of "how" you would do that - you would do it same way like you would do with any other repository azure devops supports, just pick "bitbucket cloud" when selecting the source when configuring new build.

[image]

Comment: What about bitbucket Data center?

Comment: Or do you mean Bitbucket Cloud only should be used for Bitbucket Data center as well?

Comment: OK, I'm probably mistaken. I never heard about bit bucket data center. but you can use regular git checkout